# Matching for parallel loads

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching

If there is one RF source with a known characteristic impedance, and there are multiple loads connected in parallel with each other, each with their own matching circuit, and if the electrical distance between the loads is negligible, then: would an ideally perfect match require that the equivalent total parallel resistance of the loads equal the resistance of the source? This is a theoretical question but I would eventually try applying it to a system with one antenna and three receivers. (there is no transmit.)

Here's an example. It's not optimized but it illustrates the point. Each of the matching sections is seen by the source as 900 ohms.

[image: matching Circuits]

Comment: a scematic two show your setup would help.  But I think you are right.

Comment: Load matching means input imedance = output impedance, no matter how many loads there are, or how they are disposed -- series, parallel, series+parallel, oblique w.r.t. Sagittarius A*, etc.